# Как обновить сразу два поля через Update?

Tags: postgresql, sql

имеются две таблицы A со столбцом "а"(первичный ключ) и таблица B, которая имеет так же столбец "а", который является внешним ключом A(a), мне нужно к каждому уникальному значению B(a) прибавить 1, но, что бы изменить значение B(a) мне нужно одновременно изменить те же значения в A(a), т.к. B(a) является внешним ключом A(a), и по отдельности значения поменять нельзя, если бы внешнего ключа не было, то это сделать было бы легко:

```
UPDATE B
SET a=a+1
WHERE a IN
(
        SELECT a
        FROM B
        GROUP BY a
        HAVING COUNT(a) = 1 
 )
```

Но как поменять значения одновременно в двух таблицах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но, что бы изменить значение B(a) мне нужно одновременно изменить те же значения в A(a), т.к. B(a) является внешним ключом A(a)

Вы что-то путаете. Внешний ключ - это своего рода *указатель* на данные в другой таблице, поэтому для обновления связанных данных основную таблицу трогать не надо. Если вы редактируете то уникальное значение, на которое указывает внешний ключ, то
а) Вы указали что-то неверное в качестве уникального значения и плохо понимаете свою архитектуру, либо
б) Это уникальное значение действительно изменяемо по своей природе и надо было задать внешний ключ с опцией ON UPDATE CASCADE, которое при обновлении ключа в связанной таблице автоматом обновит его и в основной.

Comment: @Fike возможно ли добавить опцию ON UPDATE CASCADE уже к существующему внешнему ключу?

Comment: @stepofchange, насколько помню, нужно дропнуть его и создать заново

Comment: @Fike спасибо!